# Duplicate grant_type parameter Uber API

Tags: oauth-2.0, uber-api, cortana, cortana-skills-kit

I'm trying to get OAuth access to Uber, using Cortana's Connected account.

All necessary for authentication data, a.k.a. auth url, token url, client secret, etc. was taken from Uber API description and passed to Cortana, so she must do all low-level job for me.

But when I'm trying to login in to uber, I receving such answer:

```
"error": "The token response status code was not 200.",
"serviceRequest": {
    "Host": "login.uber.com",
    "Headers": {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "Authorization": "Basic VXF6cGVzeWVwYXFPZDBrc0FsUTh3U0dTHFvb2k6TFg0TWFhVDRwU0NFNlM3ZDJVMGJSdlU0VnJhTnRncFJPVlo4UkNqQg=="
    },
    "Method": "POST",
    "Path": "/oauth/v2/token",
    "UrlParameters": {
        "redirect_uri": "https://www.bing.com/agents/oauth",
        "grant_type": "authorization_code",
        "code": "some code private here :)"
    },
    "PostData": "redirect_uri=https%3a%2f%2fwww.bing.com%2fagents%2foauth&grant_type=authorization_code&code=SOME_AUTHORIZATION_CODE"
},
"serviceResponse": {
    "Headers": {
        "Connection": "keep-alive",
        "Pragma": "no-cache",
        "X-Uber-App": "login",
        "Strict-Transport-Security": "max-age=604800",
        "X-Content-Type-Options": "nosniff",
        "X-XSS-Protection": "1; mode=block",
        "Cache-Control": "no-store",
        "Date": "Sat, 28 Oct 2017 10:30:57 GMT",
        "Set-Cookie": "session=421370309da06baf_59f45c61.RKb0a7144yyiV9HlZgssA5ZvSqE; Domain=login.uber.com; Secure; HttpOnly; Path=/",
        "Server": "nginx",
        "Content-Length": "84",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    "StatusCode": 400,
    "ResponseData": "{\"error_description\": \"Duplicate grant_type parameter.\", \"error\": \"invalid_request\"}"
},
```

As you can see, in property `ResponseData` I have an error: `Duplicate grant_type parameter.`

What could it be?

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to repeat the auth parameters for the token request as URL params when they are included in the POST data. I am assuming that "some code private here :)" and SOME_AUTHORIZATION_CODE are the same.

Comment: Yes, you right, this is same codes. But it's not me repeating them. Request made by Cortana and as far as I know, I can't affect to its content. 
So, in general, looks like it's how Cortana works — this service duplicates parameters in the request.